# Center map to added tile

Tags: javascript, arcgis-server

I need to create a layout with a "menu" sort of thing on the left, and on the right load a the world map. In the left menu I will have a tree, with checkboxes on the leaves. Each leave is a tile that will be loaded on it's position when the checkbox is selected. Let's say on the tree I have as parents USA and Canada. Under USA I have New York Buildings, New York Streets, Washington Buildings, and under Canada something similar. When I check New York Buildings, I need to load that tile over the map and center the map to that tile. When I click New York Streets I need the other tile to be put over this first one(it will have transparency). And so on. The main idea is that I cannot center the map to the location of the tile. Haven't tried the rest, this is where I am stuck. My code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Map";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div id="mainWindow" 
     data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" 
     data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" 
     style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="header" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">

    This is the header section
   <div id="subheader">subheader</div>

  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer">

      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
        <div id="legendDiv"></div>
      </div>

      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 2'" >
        Content for the second tab
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>

  <div id="footer" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
    this is the footer section
  </div> 
</div>
@section Head
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (Map, Tiled) {
          var tiled = new Tiled("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/arcgis/rest/services/USA/NewYork_tiles/MapServer");

          map = new Map("map", {
              basemap: "topo",
              center: [[-79.40, 43.64],
              zoom: 12
          });

          map.addLayer(tiled);
      }
    );
</script>
      }

        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
      }
</style>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>

@RenderSection("Head", false)
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body class="claro">
    @RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

this is how I found that one centers the map. But I would like to center it to the loaded tile. Also, can the folder structure with the tiles `(http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/arcgis/rest/services)` loaded in a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map object has several methods for displaying a particular view, be it centring on a MapPoint or other geometry.  For example, you could use Map.centerAt(mapPoint) if you had a map point.  What you want to do is centre on the extent of the tiled map service you've loaded so you can use map.setExtent(extent, fit) passing it the extent of the tiled service and the Boolean fit if you want it to zoom as required to fit the whole extent.  You can get the extent of the tiled service using TiledMapServiceLayer.fullExtent property.  For example:

```
map.setExtent(tiled.fullExtent, true);
```

You can subsequently put this into your check box event function so that every time it's checked it zooms to the extent (if that's how you want it to behave, another option might be to have the checkbox click event just toggle the layers visibility but then have a 'goto' button next to it that zooms to it).

You can check out more documentiontation for the map object and all of the ArcGIS API here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
As per your comment, trying to access the fullExtent property straight after the call to load the layer doesn't work because addLayer is asynchronous and so execution returns before the layer is loaded.  To set the extent straight as soon as the layer is loaded, you need to register a function to run when the layers onLoad event is raised.  The following code should achieve this:

```
var tiled = new Tiled("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/arcgis/rest/services/USA/NewYork_tiles/MapServer");
tiled.on("load", displayLayerExtent);
map.addLayer(tiled);

function displayLayerExtent(evt) {
    map.setExtent(evt.layer.fullExtent, true);
}
```

Comment: I have looked at those classes, but I had no idea what this means: "Sets the extent of the map.". What is the extent of the map? I need it to zoom on the tile I loaded. Is that "sets the extent of the map"? I will try this, not at work anymore. Thanks. Oh, and how can I get the folder structure in the code? preferably in c#.

Comment: An extent is a region/area, it is an object with a Geometry, such as a Polygon. If you zoomed the map to somewhere then the extent it's showing is everything bounded by the box created from the point at the top-left of the map object to the point at the bottom left of the map window. Similarly, everything has an extent. For example, the tiled layer you load has a fullExtent property which is the geometry you'd get if you traced a line around the outermost features within that layer. Telling the map to set the extent it is displaying to a layers full extent will centre the map on that layer.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will try it monday and will reply. Do you happen to know how to get in code that folder structure?

Comment: Regarding the folder structure, I'm not certain of what you want to do, but you could use this very good, third-party, Table Of Contents widget, which will build a table of contents based on the layers you have added to the map and for dynamic (rather than tiled) layers, builds checkboxes for sub layers.  It also displays legend graphics.  You can get it from the ArcGIS website here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109

Comment: I need to get all the folders and subfolders, for example from here:sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services .  I need to build a tree with the "Folders" section. Get all the tiles form there and load them in checkbox tree list, and when clicked, add them to the map

Comment: I have tried map = new Map("map", {
                  basemap: "topo",
                  zoom: 12
              }); 

              map.addLayer(tiled);
              map.setExtent(tiled.fullExtent, true);  but fullExtent is null and in the Console I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJson' of null

Comment: Ah, yes, thinking about it you'll need to defer the setExtent.  map.addLayer is asynchronous so it returns before the map service has actually been loaded.  That means when the setExtent us run, the services various properties haven't yet been loaded and so you get the null for fullExtent.  I'll update my example above in a moment.

Comment: wow, great, it works...phew. Thanks. Do you think I should open a new question for my folder structure tree thing?

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Yes, I'd recommend starting a new question for the other issue as this one won't attract as much attention know and I admit I don't have an answer for it.  You could also ask on http://gis.stackexchange.com as that site has more GIS oriented people.